# Getting Wrong Date from dateFormat

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

For date **Input "00/02/02"**
*formating Style is yy/MM/dd* 
 I am getting correct output like 02/01/2000

But issue is when trying with "00/01/01"
getting output like this '01/01/12100'

But I don't know why this year coming like **12100**

My code is

```
let str = "00/01/01"

let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yy/MM/dd"
if let showDate = inputFormatter.date(from: str) {
   inputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
   let resultString = inputFormatter.string(from: showDate)
   print(resultString)
 }
```

year input type always as yy format.

Comment: Actually `02/01/2000` is **not** the *correct output* 

Comment: The output for me is `01/01/2000`...

Comment: @AhmadF for me not getting  2000

Comment: @vadian its a correct output because if you not give complete year then its take it from nearest century means from 2000

Comment: I can't tell you why, but `inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`  seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav For the first example I'm expecting February `02/02/2000`

Comment: @vadian: ... and that's why I get with OP's code. Could be a typo in the question.

Comment: Setting `inputFormatter.defaultDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)` (or  any other date)  seems to help as well – don't ask me why!

Comment: @MartinR now getting correct date thnx

Comment: @MartinR setting default date to current date Date() and without setting default ,passing only time above 12 o'clock (ie "00/01/01 12:00:00") getting correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the @MartinR suggestion 
setting*inputFormatter.defaultDate to current date or Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)* its worked fine

```
let str = "00/01/01"

let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
inputFormatter.defaultDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yy/MM/dd"
if let showDate = inputFormatter.date(from: str) {
  inputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
 let resultString = inputFormatter.string(from: showDate)
 print(resultString)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce this bug by setting the timezone of the formatter, before getting the date from it, to your local timezone:

```
inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Kolkata")
//Or
inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Calcutta")
```

They both lead to `01/01/12100`.

Actually, using a date format of `yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss`, all dates starting from `00/01/01 00:00:00` to `00/01/01 05:29:59` give a  year component of `12100`. This is due to the time zone of Kolkata being offset by +05H30 from GMT. This is a bug.

Setting the timezone to UTC yields the desired output:

```
inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")  //01/01/2000
```

---

This bug occurs with other timezones too:

```
inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Africa/Addis_Ababa")
inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Moscow")
inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Hong_Kong")
```

Basically all timezones that have GMT **+** hh:mm